# Cypress : How to get returned value from custom commands ? (Cypress-promise)

Tags: javascript, promise, cypress

I'm searching a way to get back a return value returned by a custom Cypress commands.

I'm currently using Cypress and Cypress-promise lib (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-promise)

Currently, result is that:
log1=CAR 1
log2=null

Where is my mistake ?

**Test file:**

```
it('Test 1', async function() {
     const carName = await promisify(cy.set_typeCarName());
     cy.log("log2 = " + carName );
});
```

**module:**

```
set_typeCarName() {
     let carName = "CAR 1";
     cy.get('#newSiteCityInput').type(carName);
     cy.log("log1 = " + carName);
     return carName;
};

Cypress.Commands.add('set_typeCarName',() => {
    webnewsite.set_typeCarName();
});
```

Comment: Have you resolved it? Could you share with us the solution, please?

Comment: @wawanopoulos, can you mark it as solved if it was ok for you please ?

Answer (score 73):

To do this I'm using `wrap()` to return a `Chainable` containing the value I want to return.

**Module**

```
function foo() {
  return cy.wrap('foo');
}

Cypress.Commands.add('foo', foo);
```

**Test File**

```
cy.foo().then(value => console.log(value)); // foo
```

Since `wrap()` is returning a `Cypress.Chainable`, we can call `.then()` on our commands. What ever is passed into `wrap()` is yielded to the next command.

See also: [Cypress wrap() documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wrap.html#Syntax)

Comment: The way cypress reinvents Javascript is disgusting.

Comment: Thx, very useful for me :)

Comment: Nice answer, but how to pass value to foo(), like foo(param1, param2)?

Comment: @html_programmer it's been 4 days since I started working with cypress, I still don't know what the hell is going on

Answer (score 26):

Cypress introduces a new way of writing code instead of returning values, i.e. using alias. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases.html#Closures

Normal way of writing code

```
async function compute(){
const value = await (asynchronous function);
return value;
}

const x = await compute(); // #a
console.log(x);            // #b
```

How to do this is in Cypress, since we cannot use async/await in cypress

```
function() compute{
  cy.get('p#text').then(p => {
    const text = p.textContent;
    cy.wrap(text).as('pText');
    //even if we return text from here, it will not be accessible anywhere

  });
}

compute();    // #a
cy.get('@pText').then(text => {
  console.log(text);  // #b
}
```

**The crux is to alias the value and then use it in the next command

 because

Cypress first runs through whole code and puts commands in queue
 once code is in queue, next command in queue will only run after all callbacks of current command are completed, thus we can use above code pattern.**

Comment: I like that this solution addresses the async handling. I used Commands for my implementation, but found I still needed some alias handling so I fetch something from a `then` and return the mutated version through an alias in the same Command

Comment: I am shocked to read that cypress executes code differently than normal javascript is being run by engines, though it is also js

Answer (score 6):

Answer using your code

```
Cypress.Commands.add('set_typeCarName',() => {
    return cy.wrap(webnewsite.set_typeCarName()); //return the wrap and use in chain
});

function set_typeCarName() {
 let carName = "CAR 1";
 cy.get('#newSiteCityInput').type(carName);
 cy.log("log1 = " + carName);
 return carName;
};
```

Test

```
it('Test 1', async function() {
     cy.set_typeCarName().then(carName => {
         cy.log("log2 = " + carName );
     }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

One example of how to use the return value
NOTE: This method takes one numeric value e.g 3445.55 and Make it 3,445.55

Method in **Commands.js**

```
Cypress.Commands.add('getValueWithComma', (num) => {
      const n = String(num),
        p = n.indexOf('.');
      return n.replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\.|$))/g, (m, i) =>
        p < 0 || i < p ? `${m},` : m,
      );
    });
```

How to call in .spec file

```
 cy.getValueWithComma(pass_value).then((returned_value) => {
              cy.log(' Returned value is   = ', returned_value);
            });
```

Comment: Not working anymore, cypress doesn't returns the result of custom command. And throw a warning when using return in a custom command.

Answer (score 0):

PLS remember cy commands are not Promises.  You can't confidently using `async/await` and expect them to work as normal with `cy` commands.  You can use `Promise` with the `await` keyword.  And look for more info where on w3schools: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp, This help me out greatly

- Below ended up working for me in cypress

```js
// {bidderCreationRequest} was declared earlier

function createBidderObject() {
  const bidderJson = {};
  await new Promise((generateBidderObject) => {
    cy.request(bidderCreationRequest).then((bidderCreationResp) => {
      bidderJson.id = bidderDMCreationResp.body.id;

      generateBidderObject(bidderJson);
    });
  });

  return bidderJson.id
}

createBidderObject(); // returns the id of the recently created bidder instead of undefined/null
```

You can also use https://github.com/NicholasBoll/cypress-promise#readme, because the cy commands again are not Promises.  So you kinda get luck if you using `async/await` with using the native `Promise` function or the plugin mentioned

Answer (score -1):

Is the command missing a `return` statement?

```
Cypress.Commands.add('set_typeCarName',() => {
  return webnewsite.set_typeCarName(); // I added the initial `return`
});
```

Comment: Not working anymore, cypress doesn't returns the result of custom command. And throw a warning when using return in a custom command.

Answer (score -3):

I think this is what you want:

**Testfile**

```
            cy.set_typeCarName()
                .then((returned_value) => {
                    cy.log("log2 = " + returned_value)
                })
            });
```

**Module**

```
    Cypress.Commands.add('set_typeCarName',() => {
            let carName = "CAR 1";
            cy.get('#newSiteCityInput').type(carName);
            cy.log("log1 = " + carName);
            return carName;
    });
```

Comment: This seems to be the more correct answer. There is no need to wrap the return value as suggested by @8888. It is probably already wrapped by Cypress automatically.

Comment: This will throw the `CypressError: Cypress detected that you invoked one or more cy commands in a custom command but returned a different value.`. Use wrap, or return inside a `then()`, afiter your command's logic

Comment: Strongly disagree with @Kuranes here. As @Artur said, it needs to be wrapped. The Cypress error explains that it used to be wrapped automatically in earlier versions, but not anymore: `In previous versions of Cypress we automatically detected this and forced the cy commands to be returned. To make things less magical and clearer, we are now throwing an error.`

Comment: Thanks for the update! I'm unable to remove my upvote, but I will upvote @8888's answer as well. Apologies for the outdated info.