# Cypress API testing - Using custom commands to return a value to avoid duplicating code

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, cypress

First of all. I'm purposely re-learning JS/Cypress and I'm purposely starting from bedrock again, so apologies in advance.

I'm currently using Cypress for REST API testing. I am migrating tests over from an existing Ruby/Selenium framework and I want to use something similar to writing Ruby functions to clean up my code, as I am currently duplicating code.

An example:
I have a block of code that generates a date, 365 days in the past (ISOString used for a reason, in this case)

```
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 365)
    var minDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
```

I want to do something like

```
Cypress.Command.add('dateGen', () => {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() - 365)
    var minDate = date.toISOString().split('T')[0]
})
```

and call it in. In this case, I would want to call it in to my test using something like
(excuse the incorrect syntax, I'm just doing it as a like for like (Ruby/JS) illustration):
`var date = cy.dateGen`

However, running this in any js/cypress friendly combination falls over as Commands do not return values.

I am already set up to use commands in `index.js` etc, so that bit isn't causing me any problems. I am already using commands for things that don't return a value, so I know I'm doing that bit correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress : How to get returned value from custom commands ? (Cypress-promise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55847619/cypress-how-to-get-returned-value-from-custom-commands-cypress-promise)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have seen that. I was hoping that there may have been a cleaner way of doing it that didn't involved installing an npm package

Answer (score 1):

I sorted it using the following:

```
Cypress.Commands.add('dateGenerator', (days) => {
  var newDate = new Date();
  newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - days)
  var date = newDate.toISOString().split('T')[0]

  return date
})
```

and then called it via

```
cy.dateGenerator(noOfDays)
      .then((date) => {
        var minDate = date
}
```

The bit I was missing was the
`return date` and I was closing the blocks off too early in my test code.